# Обновление компонента при изменении входного параметра

Tags: vue.js

подскажите  пожалуйста как влиять на дочерний компонент из родительского. В родительском компоненте вызываю дочерний компонент:

```
<modal v-bind:showModalFlag="showModalFlag"></modal>
```

При изменении showModalFlag - компонент modal - не реагирует. То есть showModalFlag передается в дочерний компонент один раз, при старте.

showModalFlag - флаг true/false  -показать спрятать модальное окно.

Дочерний компонент:

```
<script>

    export default {

        name: "ModalForm",

        props: ["header", "showModal"],

        data: function () {

            return {

                showModalFlag: this.showModal,

            }

        },  

        methods: {

            closeModal() {

                this.showModalFlag = false;

            },                      

            saveForm() {

                this.$emit('save');

                this.showModalFlag = false;

            },                  

        },
  };

</script>

<template>

    <span>

        <transition name="modal-form">

            <div class="modal-mask"  v-show="showModalFlag">

                <div class="modal-wrapper">

                    <div class="modal-form-container">                  

                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <slot></slot>

                            <div class="modal-row">

                                <a class="btn btn-modal-cancel" v-on:click="closeModal">Cancel</a>

                                <a class="btn btn-modal-cancel" v-on:click="saveForm">Save</a>                                      

                            </div>

                        </div>                  

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </transition>

    </span>

</template>
```

Comment: покажите код дочернего компонента

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вообще в вашем случае проще сделать:

```
<modal v-if="showModalFlag"></modal>
```

или:

```
<modal v-show="showModalFlag"></modal>
```

но подозреваю, что у вас внутри дочернего компонента какая-то логика и так просто не отделаться, поэтому приведите код дочернего компонента

upd: после кода дочернего компонента всё понятно.

вообще у вас немного некорректный подход.

попробую помочь:
в data уберите возвращение showModalFlag

```
data: function () {
        return {
        }
    }
```

дальше создайте computed св-во:

```
computed: {
    showModalFlag(){
        return !!this.showModal;
    }
}
```

в методе saveForm() уберите код

```
 this.showModalFlag = false;
```

это что касалось дочернего компонента
дальше:
в родительском компоненте

```
v-bind:showModalFlag="showModalFlag"
```

переделайте на

```
v-bind:showModal="showModalFlag"
```

в назначьте обработку события @save

```
@save="showModalFlag = false;"
```

то есть итоговый код вызова модалки будет таким:

```
<modal v-bind:showModal="showModalFlag" @save="showModalFlag = false;"></modal>
```

Comment: Я добавил код дочернего компонента, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: внёс правки в ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое!